# wxPython application auto launched at system startup

Tags: wxpython, startup

I'm trying to make my wxPython application - which is previewed for launching on Windows, MacOSX and Linux - booted automatically at system startup.

AFAIK, I can use python's winreg to write a shortcut link to Windows' registry.

But is there anyway to do it which can run on all system operations?
All ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: On OSX who's screen is this going to show on - the screen is not set until the user is chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use `_winreg` to add a registry key in Windows, although I think you could also just put the shortcut into Window's special Startup folder which is buried in the User folder on newer Windows versions.

For Linux, it sounds like you could use '/etc/rc.local'. See the following link for additional details:

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=46125

On Mac, it sounds like you may need to use Automator:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4139563?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thank you. So because there is nothing like a common module which wraps these mechanisms on the whole three OSs, I just need to write one.